# What gods-related interjections were used by people in polytheistic cultures?

Tags: language

There are plenty of interjections that have nothing to do with deities. But I'm curious about deity interjections.

Presumably, people in polytheistic cultures used gods' names in analogous interjections. For example, "By Thor, my feet are sore!", "Holy Hera!", "By Mithras!", "Gods!" In fiction, Conan the barbarian frequently shouted, "Crom!"

But what kinds of interjections were actually used? What did Ancient Greeks and Romans, Vikings, Celts, etc. exclaim when they dropped a horseshoe on their toes? What did they say when surprised or awed? What did they say in enthusiasm, or hostility?

Did they mention their gods collectively?  Did they invoke the ruler of their pantheon, their personal favorite deity, or some other? Did they use the same deity each time, or different deities in different contexts (such as "by Hermes" for "travel safely" but "Zeus!" when startled by lightning)?

To what extent, if any, is this documented?

If historical evidence is absent, what might one guess based on living polytheistic religions?

*Monotheism contrast*

In cultures where Christianity is widespread, people often use "Jesus", "God", "Lord", and variants such as "jeez" as interjections or parts of interjection phrases. It's apparently a practice with sufficiently long history that ancient religious texts have declared it sinful: "Thou shalt not take the Lord's name in vain." Even non-Christians often use such interjections, such as "oh my God!", in Christianity-influenced cultures.

*Research attempts*

I did various web searches along the lines of "Ancient Greek interjections", and found no usages including gods' names, only things like "oímoi" ("woe is me"), "ágete" ("come on"), "íssa" ("you loser", roughly), "tḗnella" ("hooray"), and "khaîre" ("hello" or "goodbye").

The closest I found was "mḕ génoito" ("God forbid"), but that's not gods, plural, or a specific god.

I also tried "Celtic interjections", which mostly led to the same Greek interjections. A search for "Norse interjections gave just a few, including "hviss" ("whew").

I did not search for living polytheistic religions; my familiarity with them (other than Western neopaganism) is too thin to understand what I might find.

Comment: What about: none at all? I live in Thailand, where these kind of interjections would be considered extremely and intentionally rude.

Comment: Roman men swore by Hercules and women by Castor (https://diotima-doctafemina.org/translations/latin/aulus-gellius-introduction/aulus-gellius-11-6/).

Comment: And Ancient Greeks used "To the crows!" for "go to hell!". This wasn't related to the gods, but funeral practices: leaving your body unburied was a curse (thus, the tragedy of Antigone, where the protagonist faces a condemn to death for burying her -traitor- brother).

Comment: My Hindu friends don't use any. This isn't a history question.

Comment: You may want to look into Slavic curses/folklore, as it still includes some pre-Christian characters, like [Leshy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leshy) and [Chort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chort), and related expressions, like *Go to leshy/chort*.

Comment: If you wanted to know about the ancient Greeks and Romans and the peoples they interacted with, you could ask at the Latin site, though you might want to tighten up your question a bit before that.

Comment: I just did a quick search and "polytheistic exclamations" was more successful than interjections.  It is also possible, and might be interesting to research, whether this particular linguistic artifact is the result of religion as a unifying cultural artifact - that it might make less sense when the speaker cannot rely on the listener having the same relationship to the deity in question.  On the third hand, I'd search the Illiad for references to their Gods

Comment: Might also look at [oaths](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/14a9zb/in_your_area_of_study_how_would_people_curseswear/). I also found [neo-pagan](https://romanpagan.blogspot.com/2015/08/pagan-expletives-and-exclamations.html) the citation within is useful.

Comment: I'm surprised that this was ruled off-topic; I thought language history was a part of history. Newbie apologies! But I appreciate the answers in comments in any case.

Comment: Rereading the closure note, I see the point that language history is more about language than history. But Latin is the only applicable language, which limits the question to pre-Constantine Rome. But thanks again for the answers in the comments.

Comment: By Jove, an interesting question.

Comment: @RogerV. Leshy is the spirit of a whole single wood/forest. Chort is simply a Russian translation of a devil. They are not gods. That article you are referencing to, is extremely weak, it references to the book on Turk mythology, which is no Slav, nor even close. Much rubbish about "Slav gods" was invented as a fancy thing in the 20th Century, often even mixing Slav and Baltic gods. That about Chert - son of Chernobog - is of that sort. Absolutely no real evidence.

Comment: Dear colleagues! The author of the post asks ***were there any?***. The fact that you do not know any, proves nothing. Pure logics. As for "indecency" arguments, they are even worse. The author is obviously **not** asking about the elements of decent language, so your arguments and commentaries are also absolutely irrelevant. If somebody has problems with his religion discussing history, they are not the theme for the site.

Comment: Horatio in his first book / second satire exclaims "Great Jupiter!" ; second book/ first satire: "Oh, Jupiter, king and father!" , Persius, second satire : "Oh, Jupiter, allgood Jupiter!" Can these serve your needs?

Comment: Simply open a book of Roman satires collections and look for god names one after another - there are heaps of exclamations with gods' names.

Comment: Oh, and of course, +1 for a very interesting question.

Comment: @Gangnus it is not clear what you are referring to - Chort is indeed frequently associated with Christian devil, like in Pushkin or Gogol - but it has many traditionally Russian attributes to it. Leshy appears in folk expressions and fairy tales, alongside Baba Yaga - not sure when these began to be recorded, but they likely predate XX-th century.

Answer (score 3):

Horatio in his first book / second satire exclaims "Great Jupiter!" ; second book/ first satire: "Oh, Jupiter, king, and father!", Persius, second satire: "Oh, Jupiter, all good Jupiter!" Can these serve your needs?

If you are looking for specific expressions, open a book of Roman satire collections and look for god names one after another - there are heaps of exclamations with gods' names.

Answer (score 1):

In Greek, such as in oaths like ναὶ μὰ Δία! ("Yes, by Zeus!"). This wouldn't be used only for Zeus, but for any god or even religious-related things, like staffs or sacred places.

It's largely used with [μά](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dma%2F1).

In Latin, you had several, but popular ones included [Mehercle!/Merhercule!](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=meherc) and [Edepol!](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=edepol). Just like in Greek, tons of deities could be used in this way.

Answer (score -1):

I live in Thailand, a Buddhist country with a strong animist and polytheistic heritage. I have never ever heard a Thai utter god related interjections. Not even once. The concept is completely alien, unthinkable. That doesn't mean Thais don't cuss, they most certainly do. But never god(s) related. That would be extremely and intentionally rude.

I have heard Thais say things about the monarchy that would land them in jail for centuries, especially when stuck in traffic for hours when a royal motorcade passes by. But never god related interjections. That happened years ago, I don't remember the interjections uttered, but they were most definitely not god related.

When I queried Thais with the above question, they were surprised, even puzzled. The idea someone would do that is completely foreign to them. That is now, today. You can extrapolate that to more polytheistic cultures in the past.

Comment: According to Horatio, Romans often used such phrases as "Great Jupiter!" Notice, there is nothing offending here. Does your culture forbid even such exclamations? Why? Is mentioning the name of any god simply culturally forbidden? Notice, even the English "Goddamn!" does not offend the god. In the past, it was a short prayer asking god to do something bad to someone or something. (Nowadays, though, it practically has no sense at all.) BTW, it is a very bad idea - to extrapolate the customs of one culture to another one. It rarely works and often results in a blunder.

Comment: What about "คุณพระช่วย!"? It's not exactly the name of a deity, but it is an invocation of sorts that's used as an interjection.